# Unable to align divs properly with background image size cover using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a website with angular, bootstrap and i need the first view to be background entirely and then user can scroll down to next div but i am having trouble aligning the divs properly all day

Tried to use an img element with block size but it didn't work, tried to use padding but that completely breaks site on mobile and other size screens

Home component:

```
    <div>
      <div id="home-bg-img"></div>
      <div id="home-main">
          <div class="col-md-12 landing text-center my-auto">
            <h2 class="h2 text-light"><span class="purple">ProjectName</span></h2>
            <h3 class="h3  cosmic-purple">An Intuitive, Secure and Reliable Project.</h3>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Explore The Project</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="container col-md-12" id="home-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h3 class="h3">
              Just some text which should be beneath the image div wberjk vbetba jvntenb jtjrbsb teb jte hjkbtejknb jkbtseb gsdhjjds fhjvbjhebr hjvbdhj sbvhjds
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #home-main {
      height: 100% !important;
      width: 100% !important;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      z-index: auto;
    }
    #home-bg-img{
      position: absolute;
      min-height: 100%;
      min-width: 100%;
      background-image: url("./assets/laura-skinner-348001-unsplash.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
      background-position-x: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

I get the image aligned properly in the bg but the two DIVs are at the top of the page one after another

What i want to do is to have the text of first DIV in the center of page (horizontally and vertically) and the second div's text after the bg image after a scroll down

Comment: A few suggestions: change the `display` property; change the `position` values; use media queries to avoid breaking mobile; try creating a minimal snippet with a [placeholder image](https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=FF6347&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Image-1&w=350&h=250). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the content which should be in front of the image in the same `<div>` where the background image is applied. Also, lose the `position: absolute` property and I have added `display: flex` to center the text vertically and horizontally.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#parent-container {
  height: 100%;
}

#home-main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#home-bg-img {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=FF6347&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Image-1&w=350&h=250");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="parent-container">
  <div id="home-bg-img">
    <div class="col-md-12 landing text-center my-auto">
      <h2 class="h2 text-light"><span class="purple">ProjectName</span></h2>
      <h3 class="h3  cosmic-purple">An Intuitive, Secure and Reliable Project.</h3>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Explore The Project</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="home-main">
  <div class="container col-md-12" id="home-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h3 class="h3">
          Just some text which should be beneath the image div wberjk vbetba jvntenb jtjrbsb teb jte hjkbtejknb jkbtseb gsdhjjds fhjvbjhebr hjvbdhj sbvhjds
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```